# Is there a big difference between Atom N450 and Atom N280?

Tags: laptop, cpu, intel-atom

Is there a big difference between Atom N450 and Atom N280?

(mini laptop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, [N280](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=41411&processor=N280&spec-codes=SLGL9) is a 32-bit chip that only draws 2.5 watts. [N450](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=42503&processor=N450&spec-codes=SLBMG) is a 64-bit chip that draws 5.5 watts. Otherwise, they are the same speed and cache.

N280 was launched the first quarter of 2009, and N450 was launched the first quarter of 2010. So N450 is a newer design.

Comment: All true.  Just to add: Intel does not recommend or support using the N450 in netbooks. It's designed for desktop systems and other devices, e.g. set-top boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison of specs here, 450 has integrated graphics

http://ark.intel.com/Compare.aspx?ids=41411,42503,